# .net core cors with multiple origins and multiple headers

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I have different origins with different headers need to be allowed via cors policies.

> For example:

1/
 - Origin: abc.com
 - Headers: A, B

2/
 - Origin: bcd.com
 - Headers: A, C

> This is my code:

```
services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy(
                    "ABC",
                    builder =>
                    {
                      builder.WithOrigins("abc.com")
                          .WithHeaders("A", "B");
                    });
        opt.AddPolicy(
                    "BCD",
                    builder =>
                    {
                      builder.WithOrigins("bcd.com")
                          .WithHeaders("A", "C");
                    });
        });
```

> and in Startup.Configure:

```
builder.UseCors("ABC");
builder.UseCors("BCD");
```

Everything about the origin working ok, but the issue is about the headers. The headers are only worked for the first policy. In the code above, the headers working ok with Policy ABC. I can send the request with header A or header B as expected but for policy BCD, if I send a request with no headers. It worked but if I send a request with header A or C, it not works.

And if I move BCD on top of ABC, BCD headers works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom middleware which checks the policies based on the request's origin.

```
public class CustomCorsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ICorsService _corsService;
    private readonly ICorsPolicyProvider _corsPolicyProvider;
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _policies;

    public CustomCorsMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        ICorsService corsService,
        ICorsPolicyProvider policyProvider,
        IDictionary<string, string> policies)
    {
        _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        _corsService = corsService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(corsService));
        _corsPolicyProvider = policyProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(policyProvider));
        _policies = policies;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(CorsConstants.Origin))
        {
            string policyName;
            bool hasPolicy = this._policies.TryGetValue(context.Request.Headers[CorsConstants.Origin], out policyName);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(policyName) && hasPolicy)
            {
                CorsPolicy corsPolicy = await _corsPolicyProvider.GetPolicyAsync(context, policyName);
                if (corsPolicy != null)
                {
                    var corsResult = _corsService.EvaluatePolicy(context, corsPolicy);
                    _corsService.ApplyResult(corsResult, context.Response);

                    var accessControlRequestMethod = context.Request.Headers[CorsConstants.AccessControlRequestMethod];
                    if (string.Equals(
                            context.Request.Method,
                            CorsConstants.PreflightHttpMethod,
                            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                            !StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(accessControlRequestMethod))
                    {
                        // Since there is a policy which was identified,
                        // always respond to preflight requests.
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status204NoContent;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

In your Startup.cs you must define the policies and provide the mappings for the middleware.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
  services.AddCors(opt => {
    opt.AddPolicy(
      "ABC",
      builder => {
        builder.WithOrigins("abc.com")
          .WithHeaders("A", "B");
      }
    );
    opt.AddPolicy(
      "BCD",
      builder => {
        builder.WithOrigins("bcd.com")
          .WithHeaders("A", "C");
      }
    );
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    mappings["abc.com"] = "ABC";
    mappings["bcd.com"] = "BCD";
    app.UseMiddleware<CustomCorsMiddleware>(mappings);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any official supports from Microsoft on this case? Or did they mentioned multiple policies or multiple headers at the same time are not supported?

Comment: I didn't find any official support on your case. Although Microsoft states that you can define multiple CORS policies and assign them at the route level using EnableCors decorator, I couldn't find a better way to selectively choose between multiple policies based on the origin than defining a custom middleware.

Comment: Thank you Alex, seems like this way is the best way for now.